# How to modify/edit a Meteor package?

Tags: meteor

I want to run two different Meteor apps on the same server (on different ports) but I want to change something in one of Meteor's core packages and I want one app to use the original package and the other app to use the modified one. How could I do it?

Answer (score 21):

A bit more straightforward answer, based on answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25772395/4054019) :

1. Create packages folder in your project and change location to that folder ('cd yourproject' && 'mkdir packages' && 'cd packages')
2. Fetch files from git ('git clone https://github.com/YOUR_PACKAGE_ADDRESS' - you need to have [git installed](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git))
3. Inside fetched package folder find package.js and edit inside 'Package.describe' name value, for example by adding '-manually-modified'
4. Edit files you need to modify inside fetched package folder.
5. Add package to project (meteor add package-name-manually-modified)

Comment: Do i have to edit the path of the package in the packages folder as well?

Comment: A word of warning regarding step 3 (renaming the package). If other installed packages depend on the package being modified, renaming will cause 2 separate packages to be used: the original one and the modified one. This is probably not what you want, so it is recommended not to rename in those circumstances. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42178852/268093) as such example.

Comment: I had a problem that I couldn't modify the packages from .meteor/packages, but with this steps it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the package's files at the github repo : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages

Fetch the files you want except the  `package.js` files and add them to your project. Of note is you need to ensure their loading order sometimes so you might have to modify the file names, to have a look at the loading order have a look at `package.js`. By default meteor orders file by name but packages don't necessarily use that.

You can avoid renaming the files if you just mod the package and add it back using `meteorite` : https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite

Full instructions on how to make a `smart.json` : https://atmosphere.meteor.com/wtf/package. If its anything nice please consider adding it to [atmosphere](http://atmosphere.meteor.com) too!

Comment: I want to modify the `accounts-base` package, just one file to be more exact: `accounts_common.js`. There is the `users` collection name on line 38 and after I change it to `myusers` and place the changed file to `~/myapp/packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js` I get the following error in Firebug: `There is already a collection named 'myusers'`. I think it's because of the conflict with the original file that is running along with the modified one?

Comment: did you remove the normal `accounts-base`? If it conflicts you have two definitions of `new Collection("myusers")` somewhere

Comment: No, I did not remove the normal `accounts-base`. I just placed the changed file in an empty directory (`~/myapp/packages/accounts-base`), as you told me to do.

Comment: whoops i forgot to mention one detail, there is a distinction between server and client side code, have a look at the package.js and if its a server side file put it in `/server/` and client at `/client`. It looks like the client and server side code are conflicting

Comment: Here's the package.js: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-base/package.js Mind to have a look at it? I think it's used on the both sides.

Comment: Like this?: `~/myapp/server/packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js`

Comment: How do you handle the dependencies? For example, if a package depends on "body-parser": "1.10.1"

Answer (score 0):

I have my packages in my user folder at its root as a hidden folder called .meteor.

Perhaps you can check there? On a mac it would be under:

~/.meteor/packages/**your package name**

You must also now go into a file there os.json, and change the "length" variable for the file you changed to match the new byte file size. Otherwise it might not compile, but try compiling first and see if its an issue that you changed some package code.