# How to modify already installed Atmosphere packages

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Before meteor 0.9.0 I could edit Atmosphere package files after it has been installed. Now templates are pre-compiled and hidden in meteor core, so I can't edit html(templates).

I found only way to have modified package. Load it from GitHub, modify it and then add as app-specific packages to the /packages directory. Then I can continuously modify this package.

Does anyone know better way ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you are right, for example with this package mrt:accounts-t9n, I have following this steps

> 1- cd yourproject && mkdir packages && cd packages
>  2- git clone
>   https://github.com/softwarerero/meteor-accounts-t9n.git
>  3- cd
>   meteor-accounts-t9n
>  4- edit package.js and change line 4 to name:
>   "mrt:accounts-t9n"
>  5- cd .. && meteor add mrt:accounts-t9n

for this moment is the solution, I don't find another.

Comment: should I remove "mrt:" prefix before package name ?

Comment: yes, you should to remove the previous package and after that install the new package.

Comment: hmmm, but does it mean that templates will not be pre-compiled ?