# How to edit the package telescope-posts?

Tags: meteor, telescope

I installed the package telescope-posts through "meteor add telescope:posts"

I wanted to edit the posts.js file inside of it but I could not find it, so I downloaded the zip from the TelescopeJS github page and tried dragging the telescopes-post folder into my .meteor folder. I then opened posts.js in Sublime text and edited the following lines:

```
/**
Post body (markdown)
*/
body: {
type: String,
optional: false,
max: 10000,
editableBy: ["member", "admin"],
autoform: {
  rows: 10
}
},
```

I changed "max" from "3000" to "10000" in an attempt to make the character limit higher so that they could write more. I did "mup deploy" but when I tried to write more in the "body" box, I could still only write the small amount from before. Did I put the folder in the wrong place? How can I give the user a higher character limit? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify already installed Atmosphere packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772226/how-to-modify-already-installed-atmosphere-packages)

Comment: I don't think that was able to help me. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, You can't edit packages like you have described - you have to follow the instructions in the answer that I referenced.

[How to modify already installed Atmosphere packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772226/how-to-modify-already-installed-atmosphere-packages)

Remove the package, clone it from github, change the name, and add it to your app as an app specific package. Then you can make any changes you need :)

Comment: Everything seemed to go smoothly but it ended up not working. Thank you anyways!