# Installing meteor package,local or github

Tags: meteor

I was having issues with this datepicker package for autoform https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform-bs-datetimepicker and the fix was in another repo https://github.com/stefanve/meteor-autoform-bs-datetimepicker and was two commits ahead https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform-bs-datetimepicker/compare/master...stefanve:master

I went to my packages folder,which was empty and i git clone the repo containing the fixes https://github.com/stefanve/meteor-autoform-bs-datetimepicker.git

I was following this post instructions [How to modify already installed Atmosphere packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772226/how-to-modify-already-installed-atmosphere-packages) on how to install a package locally.

I tried installing the package while at the packages dir but got an error that the package is unknown.

I tried editing the packages file to this

```
Package.describe({
    name: 'stefanve:autoform-bs-datetimepicker',
    summary: 'Custom bootstrap-datetimepicker input type with timezone support for AutoForm',
    version: '1.0.6',
    git: 'https://github.com/stefanve/meteor-autoform-bs-datetimepicker.git'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.use('templating@1.0.0');
  api.use('blaze@2.0.0');
  api.use('aldeed:autoform@4.0.0 || 5.0.0');

  // Ensure momentjs packages load before this one if used
  api.use('momentjs:moment@2.8.4', 'client', {weak: true});
  api.use('mrt:moment-timezone@0.2.1', 'client', {weak: true});

  api.addFiles([
    'autoform-bs-datetimepicker.html',
    'autoform-bs-datetimepicker.js'
  ], 'client');
});
```

and my package was installed.

M question is,did meteor install the packae from the files i cloned or did it get from github?.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor doesn't install packages from github. It simply can't do that.

The list of packages are in `.meteor/packages` file. If there's a matching name in your local `packages` folder, then it will load from there, otherwise from Atmosphere (local has more priority than Atmosphere).

Try changing the `version` in package.js and see how it reloaded your package and updated `.meteor/versions`.

Comment: Good idea.I will change the version and see.