# Meteor Yogiben:Admin Filtering by Logged in User

Tags: meteor, collections, meteor-autoform, subscriptions

I am using the [yogiben:admin](https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-admin) package for meteor and I would like the currently logged in user to be able to see only their own objects from each collection.

How do I integrate subscriptions into the admin?   Is it part of autoform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am starting to figure it out.

I cloned the package using the technique described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30864393/55124

Now I am looking into the lib/server/publish.coffee file to edit the publication.

```
Meteor.publishComposite 'adminCollectionDoc', (collection, id) ->
    check collection, String
    check id, Match.OneOf(String, Mongo.ObjectID)
    if Roles.userIsInRole this.userId, ['admin']
        find: ->
            adminCollectionObject(collection).find(id)
        children: AdminConfig?.collections?[collection]?.children or []
    else
        @ready()

Meteor.publish 'adminUsers', ->
    if Roles.userIsInRole @userId, ['admin']
        Meteor.users.find()
    else
        @ready()

Meteor.publish 'adminUser', ->
    Meteor.users.find @userId

Meteor.publish 'adminCollectionsCount', ->
    handles = []
    self = @

_.each AdminTables, (table, name) ->
    id = new Mongo.ObjectID
    count = 0
    table = AdminTables[name]
    ready = false
    selector = if table.selector then table.selector(self.userId) else {}
    handles.push table.collection.find().observeChanges
        added: ->
            count += 1
            ready and self.changed 'adminCollectionsCount', id, {count: count}
        removed: ->
            count -= 1
            ready and self.changed 'adminCollectionsCount', id, {count: count}
    ready = true

    self.added 'adminCollectionsCount', id, {collection: name, count: count}

self.onStop ->
    _.each handles, (handle) -> handle.stop()
self.ready()

Meteor.publish null, ->
    Meteor.roles.find({})
```

But it turns out, it is as simple as changing the a line in lib/both/startup.js

```
return AdminTables[name] = new Tabular.Table({
  name: name,
  collection: adminCollectionObject(name),
  pub: collection.children && adminTablePubName(name),
  sub: collection.sub,
  columns: columns,
  extraFields: collection.extraFields,
  dom: adminTablesDom,
  selector: collection.selector || function( userId ) {
    return { owner: userId };
  }
```

There was an empty selector function and I've added return owner: userId.