# How to modify package that is dependency of other packages - MeteorJS

Tags: meteor, package

So, my problem is that I am trying to add a couple of console.log() to a js file of an already installed package that I have in my project.

The package that I am trying to add these lines to is `aldeed:autoform`, since I've discovered kind of a bug in a function and I want to contribute with a solution.

In order to modify a package, I have already done the following steps:

1. Clone the github repo for autoform inside `myProject/packages/` folder.
2. Modified the lines that I wanted to.
3. Changed the name value inside `Package.describe({})` (set to
   `aldeed-autoform-modified`)
4. Removed `aldeed:autoform` from my project (`meteor remove
   aldeed:autoform`)
5. Added my modified version of autoform (`meteor add
   aldeed:autoform-modified`)

The problem is that, since I am also using antoher packages that have `aldeed:autoform` as a dependency, this package gets automatically installed, and then when I run my project, it trhows an error saying that a template (related to AutoForm) is defined twice, and this makes sense since autoform package and the modified one have this templated defined, and both get included in the project.

What should I do? What is the proper way to modify a package that is a dependency for others?

Comment: Why change the name? The local version should override the one available online.

Comment: I saw that recomendation here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765591/how-to-modify-edit-a-meteor-package)

Comment: @MasterAM Yes! It worked. Changed the name back to `aldeed:autoform` in the local version and it overwritten the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify an existing package, you can use a local version of it.

There is no need to modify its name, and if another package depends on it, changing the name will cause the dependent package not to use your modified version.

Simply clone the package repository into your projects's`/packages` directory or to the directory denoted by the `METEOR_PACKAGE_DIRS` environment variable.

You can find more details on the [Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/writing-atmosphere-packages.html#overriding-atmosphere-packages).